# How to update data custom table in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to update data by id, I tried this code but it adds new data, not update data, how to update it? please help me

My code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getParam('general');
    $model = $this->dailyOffers->create();
    $model->load($data['id']);
    $model->setData([
            "product_id" => $data['product_id'],
            "product_name" => $data['product_name'],
            "product_sku" => $data['product_sku'],
            "placement" => $data['placement'],
            "start_date" => $data['start_date'],
            "end_date" => $data['end_date'],
            "offer_price" => $data['offer_price'],
            "is_active" => $data['is_active']
            ]);
    $saveData = $model->save();
```

Comment: Please check the value of `$data['id']`, after loading the model, we can check the existing of item or not `if ($model->getId())`

Comment: load vào đúng anh ơi, _dump ra đúng, mà setData với save thì nó luưu cái mới

Comment: did you solve the issue?